# Why does Поднят ворот mean collar is raised? Collar doesn't seem to be the meaning of ворот

Tags: перевод

I'm trying to learn the lyrics and meaning of a song in russian (Мой друг - лучше всех играет блюз) and the first line is Поднят ворот, both unfamiliar words to me. A translation I found put them as meaning "his collar is raised", but it seems to me that Поднят ворот would mean the gate is raised. Is that a correct translation? If so, is ворот the word you would ordinarily use to mean collar?

As a side note, the title of the song "Мой друг - лучше всех играет блюз": is that "my freind, the best of all play the blues", or "my freind is the best blues player of all"?

Thanks if anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: Have you considered looking it up [in a dictionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82#%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82_I) or something?

Comment: To be exact, it's "my friend plays blues best of all."

Comment: _Ворот_ if in nominative case doesn't mean _the gates_, that's _ворота_; though in a context of mechanical devices  _ворот_ could mean a rotational mechanism (_поворотный механизм_) that raises the bridge or opens the gates.  

But here we have more like clothing/garment context though and @YellowSky comment below on the difference between _воротник_ and _ворот_ is a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on reddit cleared it up for me. ворот is an abreiviation of воротник which means collar.

Comment: _Ворот_ is not an abbreviation, it's a full noun, _воротник_ is just another noun formed from _ворот_ with the help of the word-building suffix _-ник_ with various meanings, here it adds practically no new elements of meaning to _ворот_, maybe a shade of diminutiveness, 'little collar'.

Comment: "Ворот" is very rarely used nowadays in the meaning of "воротник". However, you should be able to find it in any dictionary.

Comment: @Alexander - Technically,  _воротник_ and _ворот_ are partial synonyms and can mean different things, especially for a tailor. Every shirt has _ворот_ (the part around the neck), but not every shirt has _воротник_ (a piece of cloth attached to the shirt around the neck). A typical T-shirt has _ворот_ but doesn't have _воротник_.